# SQL - make a column unique after some timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Here is my use case.

I am using `Postgres 13.3`

I have a `people` table under a `draft` schema that has multiple columns.. `email` and created_at. The email should have been unique but it was not. If I alter the table to be unique, there were duplicate emails inserted before and I don't want to lose the data by removing all the duplicates. can I make the constraint to make the email unique after now or the current timestamp?

I have tried this which obviously is a syntax error

```
ALTER TABLE draft.people ADD UNIQUE (email) WHERE created_at > timestamp()
```

I also tried to add a check constraint but it throws a syntax error..should I write a function that is triggered before insert?

Comment: Why cant you handle this in your code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can only be done using a unique index.

However, you can not use `current_timestamp` or `now()` in the WHERE condition. You need to put in a constant value:

```
create unique index on draft.people (email) 
WHERE created_at > timestamp '2022-08-12 22:00:00';
```

Comment: It worked! But just removed the timestamp.